# QT Android UnsatisfiedLinkError Cannot load library

Tags: android, qt

Project.pro file:

```
LIBS += -LF:/Path/lib/ -lmyLibrary
INCLUDEPATH += F:/Path/include/
```

After project run I have RuntimeError.
Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10303): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1936]:    85 could not load needed library 'libmyLibrary.so' for 'libProject.so' (load_library[1091]: Library 'libmyLibrary.so' not found)
E/AndroidRuntime(10303):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
E/AndroidRuntime(10303):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by adding this line to `.pro` file:

```
ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS += F:/Path/lib/ -lmyLibrary.so
```